# Generate a sequence number for every 3 rows in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to generate a `sequence number` for every `three rows` with some range. can this be done without iterations.

Example:

```
sequence
--------
1
1
1
2
2
2
3
3
3
```

Comment: There is still problem.you have not mention in which scenario you want such sequence. What is the actual query like ?Knowing that can make query easier .

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use this `Analytic function`

```
SELECT ( ( Row_number()OVER(ORDER BY order_by_column ) - 1 ) / 3 ) + 1 seq_no,
              *
       FROM   tablename
```

Comment: Pretty clever use of integer division.